# Vue: event emitted is not getting picked up

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-blade

I am able to pick up fire `emitgetcartitems` but for some reason the other listener, `emitaddnotes`, is not firing `handleAddNotes()`.  I checked in context of the component as well by checking `this.$listeners` and I only saw `emitgetcartitems` listed for it.  I'm not sure why the other event is not working at all.

**blade template**

```html
<div id = "app"> 

    <Modal
      :modal-type="modalType"
      :selected-product="selectedProduct"
      :variant-data="variantData" 
      @emitgetcartitems="handleGetCartItems"
      @emitaddnotes="handleAddNotes"

    >
    </Modal>
    <Cart>
    </Cart>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```js
window.Vue = require('vue');
window.axios = require('axios');

Vue.component('Modal', 
  require('./components/Modal.vue').default);


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      modalType: null,
      orderNotes: null,
      couponCode: null,
      selectedProduct: {},
      variantData: [],
      cart: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleChangeTab: function(tab) {
       this.activeTab = tab
    },
    handleHideFlashMsg: function() {
      this.flashStatus = false
    },
    handleAddNotes: function(){
      console.log("!!!!!!!")
    },
    handleGetCartItems: function() {
        axios
            .get('/api/a-cart')
            .then(response => {
                this.cart = response.cart;
            });
    },

  }
)}
```

**Modal.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button v-on:click="addNotes()"></button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
          return {
          couponInput: '',
          }
    },
        props: {
          selectedProduct: {type: Object},
          orderNotes: {type: String},
          couponCode: {type: String}
        },
        methods: {
            getCartItems: function() {
                        console.log("GET CART")
                this.$emit('emitgetcartitems')
            },
            addNotes: function() {
                     console.log("ADD NOTES")
              this.$emit('emitaddnotes')
            },  
      }
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Do you get the console message _"ADD NOTES"_ when you click the button?

Comment: @Phil yes, it's logging "ADD NOTES" but that's all

Comment: I could add another JSFiddle demo (like your last question) but I can tell you that it too, will work as expected. I'm starting to think there's something wrong with your build environment

Comment: strange, thanks @Phil .  Looking at it though, nothing seems off?  I was pulling my hair thinking I was using the emit syntax incorrectly

Comment: You say you can see `emitgetcartitems` working but I can't see anything that executes the `getCartItems()` method on your `Modal` component. So how is that working?

Comment: same way-- I just omitted that from the template for clarity : `<button v-on:click="getCartItems()"></button>`

Comment: Omitting things is not helping

Comment: Your main file has `)}` at the end, but it should be `})`.